Notify client when publish_data is run
ipyparallel.datapub has a publish_data function. Is there any way to have the client react when the corresponding AsyncResult.data attribute is updated ?
import ipyparallel as ipp

c = ipp.Client()
dv = c[:]
dv.block = False

def publish_it():
    from ipyparallel.datapub import publish_data
    from time import sleep
    lst = []
    for i in range(100):
        # We update the list 'lst' every second
        lst.append(i)
        publish_data(dict(a=lst))
        sleep(1)

ar = dv.apply_async(publish_it)

Is there a means for the client to react (e.g to print something) every time the list is updated ?
